# Can I do multiple SQL requests as a single request

Tags: sql, optimization

here's the situation, i have 3 tables that look like this.

```
table foo
type number
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4

table bar
number shape
1      square
2      circle
3      triangle
4      rectangle

table foobar
shape     colour 
square    red
circle    green
triangle  blue
rectangle yellow
triangle  purple
```

they all also have unique ids that I have not listed.
I have type but I want to find colour. now I could do three SQL requests to get it but as the SQL is likely to be the bottleneck so I was wondering if I could combine the three SQL requests into one request.

Is it possible to do this and would it run faster than three separate SQL requests

1 would return red and 3 would return blue and purple.

Comment: could you show us an example of the output you want?

Comment: Maybe if you explain the 3 requests you want to do it will be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT fb.colour
FROM foo AS f
INNER JOIN bar AS b ON f.number = b.number
INNER JOIN foobar AS fb ON b.shape = fb.shape
WHERE f.type = "YOURTYPE"
```

You can use  [`JOINS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) to join the rows and use a where clause to specify the type you want. It would definitely be faster then doing this:

```
SELECT number FROM foo WHERE type="YOURTYPE"
SELECT shape  FROM bar WHERE number="NUMBERRETRIEVEDFROM"
SELECT colour FROM foobar WHERE shape="SHAPE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT C.colour
FROM foo AS A, bar AS B, foobar AS C
WHERE A.number = B.number
AND B.shape = C.shape
WHERE A.type = '<YOUR-TYPE>'
```

Comment: This is cartesian product you should use JOIN instead (postgres fixes this automatically though but dont rely on it for other dbms)